# Intellij idea shows that I am using a different version of the dependency

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Java/ Kotlin project that uses gradle. When I try to run it everything is fine but intellij idea shows an error and also says that I use a different version of the dependency than that I am using.

Here some screenshots:

[image: Error]
[image: Dependency manager]

And this is what I put in my build.gradle:

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0")
```

So was wondering what I have to change for intellij idea to recognize it correctly

Edit:
Also tried adding:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        failOnVersionConflict()

        preferProjectModules()

        force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0'
    }
}
```

But got the same error in intellij idea.

Edit 2:
When running the following command: `./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency okhttp` I get this:

```
com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0
  Variant apiElements:
    | Attribute Name                     | Provided     | Requested    |
    |------------------------------------|--------------|--------------|
    | org.gradle.status                  | release      |              |
    | org.gradle.category                | library      | library      |
    | org.gradle.dependency.bundling     | external     | external     |
    | org.gradle.jvm.environment         | standard-jvm | standard-jvm |
    | org.gradle.jvm.version             | 8            | 8            |
    | org.gradle.libraryelements         | jar          | classes      |
    | org.gradle.usage                   | java-api     | java-api     |
    | org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type | jvm          | jvm          |
   Selection reasons:
      - By conflict resolution: between versions 4.11.0 and 3.14.9

com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0
\--- compileClasspath

com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9 -> 4.11.0
\--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0
     +--- compileClasspath
     +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0
     |    \--- compileClasspath
     +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jaxb:2.9.0
     |    \--- compileClasspath
     \--- com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0
          \--- compileClasspath
```

Comment: Does it work if you replace "call.request().url" with "call.request().url()"?

Comment: Intellij idea won't complain then anymore but gradle will then fail when running

Comment: Try to close the IDE and delete okhttp3 dependency from the local .m2 folder on your PC. Then re-open the project in IntelliJ IDEA and click on `Reload All Projects` button in the Gradle tool window

Comment: @EgorKlepikov sadly have the same error. Tried to remove the .gradle first and afterwards the .m2 but that didn't help

Comment: What does `./gradlew dependencies` show?  That route is more reliable than going through IJ.

Comment: So it looks like Gradle has the correct version and it's an IJ problem...  From there, I'd use the "Invalidate caches and restart".  Then, escalate to close IJ/delete `.idea/` folder, remove project from recent, and re-open... likely one of those would work.

Comment: @User51 had already tried the Invalidate caches and restart and now also the removal of the .idea folder but that did not resolve it

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please report this issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project (can be attached privately) and screenshots showing the error. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrey found what caused it but still think this is a bug (or I just don't fully understand how gradle works). But made a bug report with a sample project attached: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-326624/Intellij-idea-shows-the-wrong-dependency-version-in-the-main-project-when-another-included-project-uses-the-older-version